# Custom List Adapter want to refresh when loads json

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter, android-json

I am using custom Adapter to view the json datas. If I reload again the data was repeated again. I tried to adapter.clear(). How to refresh the custom adapter listview. My code is.

From json the value is setting to the adapter

```
for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){
                    String j_hotel_id=data.getJSONObject(i).getString("hotel_id");
                    String j_hotel_name=data.getJSONObject(i).getString("hotel_name");
                    String j_hotel_place=data.getJSONObject(i).getString("city");
                    String j_hotel_date=data.getJSONObject(i).getString("created_date");

                    hotel_id1.add(j_hotel_id);  //Arraylist                 
                    hotel_name1.add(j_hotel_name);  //Arraylist                         
                    hotel_place1.add(j_hotel_place);    //Arraylist                         
                    h_created_date1.add(j_hotel_date);  //Arraylist 
                    //count++;
                }
list_hotel.setAdapter(new HotelCustomAdapter(this, hotel_id1,hotel_name1,hotel_place1)); // passing to custom Adapter and list_hotel is the ListView id
```

The custom adapter is

```
        package ridio.helixtech;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import ridio.helixtech.RateCustomAdapter.Holder;

    public class HotelCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{ 

        List<String> h_id=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> h_name=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> h_place=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> h_date=new ArrayList<String>();
        Context context;
          private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;


        public HotelCustomAdapter(HotelMaster hotelAdd1, List<String> hotel_id1, List<String> hotel_name1,
                List<String> hotel_place1, List<String> h_created_date1) {
            h_id=hotel_id1;
            h_name=hotel_name1;
            h_place=hotel_place1;
            h_date=h_created_date1;
            context=hotelAdd1;
             inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                     getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        public HotelCustomAdapter(HotelMaster hotelAdd1, List<String> hotel_id1, List<String> hotel_name1,
                List<String> hotel_place1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            h_id=hotel_id1;
            h_name=hotel_name1;
            h_place=hotel_place1;
            context=hotelAdd1;
             inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                     getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return h_id.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder
        {
            TextView tv;
            TextView tv1;
            TextView tv2;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final Object[] id_obj=h_id.toArray();
            Object[] name_obj=h_name.toArray();
            Object[] place_obj=h_place.toArray();
            Holder holder=new Holder();
            View rowView;       
                 rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hotel_custom_listview, null);
                 holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.h_id);
                 holder.tv1=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.h_name);
                 holder.tv2=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.h_place);
             holder.tv.setText(""+id_obj[position]);
             holder.tv1.setText((CharSequence) name_obj[position]);
             holder.tv2.setText((CharSequence) place_obj[position]);
             rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+id_obj[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });   
            return rowView;
        }

    }
```

How to refresh the adapter from this code.

Again I tried to pass the count value to get the json array from that last count it was not loading from database. If I use global value to the for loop, 1st time it was not loading the json second time loading the value perfectly. I am not changing the value anywhere except in the loop. I am totally confused. The below code I used.

```
 int count=0; //Global value
 for(int i=count;i<data.length();count++){
                    String j_hotel_id=data.getJSONObject(count).getString("hotel_id");
                    String j_hotel_name=data.getJSONObject(count).getString("hotel_name");
                    String j_hotel_place=data.getJSONObject(count).getString("city");
                    String j_hotel_date=data.getJSONObject(count).getString("created_date");

                    hotel_id1.add(j_hotel_id);  //Arraylist                 
                    hotel_name1.add(j_hotel_name);  //Arraylist                         
                    hotel_place1.add(j_hotel_place);    //Arraylist                         
                    h_created_date1.add(j_hotel_date);  //Arraylist 
                    //count++;
                }
```

Comment: Where do you create 'hotel_id1' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `adapter.invalidate()` or `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you changed your data.

In your case:
`list_hotel.getAdapter().invalidate();` or `list_hotel.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Tried @Jelle not worked. Your 1st solution was not working. Second one crashing. Me edited the question please look at once again.

Comment: Worked by clearing all the Arraylist before executing the for loop.            hotel_id1.clear();  //Arraylist                 
                    hotel_name1.clear();  //Arraylist                         
                    hotel_place1.clear();    //Arraylist                         
                    h_created_date1.clear();    //Arraylist   ( thanks @Jelle )